# Error de ejecución con Trigger en Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

lo que intento crear con este trigger es que pasada la fecha del campo **VIG_CHAR** el estado (campo **FLAG_CHAR**) de ese registro pase a ser 0 pero me genera el error **ORA-04091** y cuando paso al debug mi variable **vigenciaCharla** toma como valor **NULL**.

Este es mi trigger:

```
create or replace trigger OCEX_validaFlag
after insert or update on OCEX_CHARLA
for each row
declare
    vigenciaCharla date;
begin

    select max(vig_char)
    into vigenciaCharla
    from ocex_charla
    where cip_per = :new.cip_per and flag_charla = '1';

    IF(SYSDATE > vigenciaCharla) THEN
        UPDATE OCEX_CHARLA set flag_charla = '0' where cip_per = :new.cip_per;
    END IF;
end OCEX_validaFlag;
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error [ORA-04091](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora04091.php) se conoce como el error de "tabla mutante", el problema es simple, en un trigger no puedes leer ni actualizar la tabla asociada al mismo. Esto tiene sentido ya que habría un problema de recursión, actualizar una tabla dispara un trigger que actualiza la tabla que dispara el trigger.. etc, etc.

La solución es usar los valores `:NEW` y `:OLD`.

No tengo forma de evaluar tu código, pero entendiendo lo que dices, podrías ser algo así:

```
create or replace trigger OCEX_validaFlag
after insert or update on OCEX_CHARLA
for each row
begin
    IF(SYSDATE > :NEW.vig_char) THEN
        :NEW.flag_charla = '0';
    END IF;
end OCEX_validaFlag
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, una consulta ... hay manera de hacer que ese trigger se ejecute todos los días para hacer la verificación de la fecha y se cambie automáticamente su estado del **FLAG_CHARLA**?

Comment: No, los triggers se ejecutan antes o después de  un evento de actualización de tablas, para lo preguntas te convendría investigar por el lado de un JOB: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#ADMIN12062

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.